# All android processes crash when booting device

Tags: samsung, crashes, system-error

Today I turned on my tablet (a **Samsung Galaxy Tab A6**). I was expecting to see the usual home screen, but as soon as the operating system loaded, I got a lot of process crash errors. **Please note that I'm not opening any of these apps, the error messages are appearing by themselves.**

All the error messages are overlapping.

Here are some of the processes that are crashing:

```
system
android.process.acore
android.process.media
External Storage
EmergencyProvider
LogsProvider
BadgeProvider
AutoPreconfig
Google One Time Init 
Samsung Push Service 
Bluetooth 
Camera
```

These are just a few, the device suddenly reboots after a while (it doesn't always reboot automatically).

When I boot the tablet, it shows, behind the error messages, a **welcome screen** (the one that appears when you buy a device and boot it for the first time). This welcome screen is unusual, as I never formatted the tablet's memory.

Here's a photo, so I can explain better.
[image: The error message over the welcome screen]

Without knowing how, I got to the main screen, requiring me to put the SIM Card code. As soon as I put the code, other process crash messages kept appearing, so it's **impossible** to go even to the Home Launcher.

I'm wondering if there's a solution to this big problem, and what it has been caused by (a virus, file corruption...).

Please, I need help. I don't know why I get these error messages, and I didn't find any solution to this problem on the Internet.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You can try to put your device in Download Mode and connect it to Samsung pc program and restore the rom.

Comment: Did you try performing a factory reset? Seems like data got corrupted

Comment: I performed a factory reset. The problem is that now Google is asking for my account's phone number (a old number I had and I don't even remember it). Do you know any way to bypass this lock?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this problem. I just booted into recovery mode, and I deleted all data.
After rebooting, the system started working as usual, even though I erased all my data, which I successfully recovered since I made a backup some time before.